# Jasper Reports Group VS Oracle Order By

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a report that I am in the process of converting from Crystal Reports to JasperReports.  I am designing the report using iReport 4.5 and JasperReport Server 4.5. Oracle Stored Procedure that returns `REF_CURSORS` is used to populate data.  Below is a sample SQL:

```
Select First_Name, Last_Name, DOB, City From PPL Order By DOB;
```

When I use this SQL in the report designer and design a report and I create groups as follows

Parent Group is First_Name
Second Group is City

Basically I want to group all the people with similar first name in the all the cities it applies.

Expected results:

```
First_Name       Last_Name      DOB              City
Alan             Kum            10/01/2010       Mumb
Alan             Boss           01/10/2001       Mumb 
Alan             Cross          10/10/2000       Irvn
```

But since the SQL has an order by clause my data is not displayed in the expected manner as displayed above.  How do I overcome this issue?

The issue is I can not change the procedure as it's being used in the application and also an Excel version of the report uses the same query where they want to see the data in order by DOB.

Comment: Do you really need to group data inside your report? I think you can skip that part of process.

Comment: As i mentioned in my original message its a conversion report so I cannot skip anything.... that includes the Group....

Answer (score 0):

Well... the "correct" solution is to change the query to order by the fields you want to order by: First_Name, City (and then perhaps by DOB or Last_Name to have a fully deterministic ordering).

But since you don't have that option available to you, you can instead do the sorting in JasperReports. Edit your query and then click the button "Sort options...". This should allow you to re-sort the data as you like. It will be slower sorting in the report engine, but slower and correct is far better than a quick result which doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: Sorry where do I find the button "Sort options..."  I am using iReport designer 4.5...Also The sample query stated above is in a stored procedure that returns a REF_CURSOR...

Comment: Never mind I found where the button is... its available in the bottom section in the area where you add the query / procedure reference...